# Android Studio cannot update and resolve changes in XML to preview

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to create a layout for my application in Android Studio. Sadly, not all changes that I've applied in text mode editing appear in the preview mode. Here's the example: despite hardcoding a text displayed on a button, the preview still displays "Button", instead of "Find Gyms". What could be the solution? I have already tried to re-sync and invalidate/restart. Note: the Material Search Bar does not appear properly either, though I'm not sure if for the same reason.
[image: example]

Comment: If you remove the `MaterialSearchBar` and just leave the `Button` does it show the text?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS no, nothing happens

Comment: Did you clean the project? or rebuild it?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS yes, even before posting the question